# replace the space between the nodes with the &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like

```
var data="<html> <div style=""> fasf saf <div></html>"
```

output should be like

```
var data="<html>&npsp<div style"">&nbsp;fasf&nbsp;saf&nbsp;<div></html>"
```

Comment: Recommendation: Don't use regex to process HTML text, since HTML text is too complex for regex to handle correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone pointed out, you should not use regular expressions to parse html, it is too complex in general ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1) there's a nice discussion).

Also, you are missing a closing tag for your last div, it should be :

```
...</div></html>
```

Finally, if you still want to use regex, you could try to find '>\s+<' and replace with '>&npsp<' to replace spaces between different tags.

It is much more difficult replacing spaces within tags, i think you really should avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using DOM.

```
//create a dummy div.
var elem = document.createElement("div");
//now append the text as child.
elem.innerHTML = data;
//now get the string that needs the edit.
//if you have multiple divs iterate through the elements and do the following.
var temp = elem.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML;
temp = temp.replace(new RegExp(" ","g"),"&nbsp");
//finally update the div and get back edited data.
elem.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = temp;
data = elem.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have space in tag so can't replace simply. Try it:

```js
var data="<html> <div style=''> fasf saf <div></html>";
var strs = data.split(''); 
var openTag = false;
for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
  if(strs[i]=="<")
    openTag = true;
  if(strs[i]==">")
    openTag = false; 
  if(!openTag && strs[i] == " ")
    strs[i] = "&nbsp;"
}
console.log(strs.join(''));
```